# Examples of plane algebraic curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-curves

There are many interesting sequences of polynomials which contain
polynomials of arbitrarily high degree, for example classical
orthogonal polynomials. Most of them arise as characteristic polynomials
of some sequences of operators, or as polynomial solutions
of some differential equations.

> What are some natural specific
> sequences of plane (affine or projective) algebraic
> curves which contain curves of arbitrarily high degree and genus?

One such example is Fermat's curves $x^n+y^n=1$. [Lissajous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lissajous_curve)
(a.k.a. Chebyshev)
curves are of arbitrary degree but they have zero genus.  Sequences of hyperelliptic curves occur in the theory of integrable systems. What else?

I looked to the Catalog of Plane curves by D. Lawrence (Dover, 2014)
and to the book of Brieskorn and Knörrer, Plane algebraic curves,
and found only Lissajous curves, [epitrochoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epitrochoid) and
[hypotrochoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypotrochoid) (all of genus zero) as examples of arbitrarily high degree.

I understand that many examples can be constructed. But I am asking on some naturally occuring sequences, whatever it can mean. Of some historical significance or appearing in applications.

EDIT. Thanks to all who answered or commented. I am not marking this question as "answered" for a while, hoping for more examples. Of course, [classical modular curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_modular_curve) belong here, thanks to Felipe Voloch.
Let me mention my motivation for this question. For some time I am studying what can be called "Lamé modular curves" (surprisingly, there is no established name for them). [Lamé functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lam%C3%A9_function)
are solutions of Lamé's differential equation whose squares are polynomials. Existence of
such a solution imposes a polynomial equation connecting the modulus of the
torus $J$ and an "accessory parameter". These polynomials define a family of plane affine algebraic curves
which contains curves of arbitrary degree and genus, and their coefficients are integers.

Comment: what do you mean by the degree of modular curves? Do they come with some kind of canonical embedding into the projective plane?

Comment: I’m ashamed to say, I don’t know if the *n*th caustic by reflection (of rays through a point) at a circle (Holditch [1858](//books.google.com/books?id=hRELAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA301); [pictures](//arxiv.org/abs/math/0411189)) is algebraic. The 1st is, by St-Laurent ([1826](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=AMPA_1826-1827__17__128_0), p. 134) or Cayley ([1857](//archive.org/details/collmathpapers02caylrich/page/n353), pp. 353-355) who also cites a paper of Lagrange I was never able to find. There may be something to Thm 6 of Glaeser-Schröcker ([2000](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2001g:51016)).

Comment: @vrz: frankly speaking, I don't know.

Comment: There will probably be many examples from combinatorics, e. g. Tutte Polynomials (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_polynomial). I do not know/have not tried to prove that there are Tutte Polynomials with arbitrarily high genus, but seems entirely plausible.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko then presumably you should not say that modular curves contain curves of arbitrarily high degree (I am not sure if you are in fact saying it but that is the way I parsed the question). Maybe the question could be rephrased to be more clear on this point?

Comment: @auniket: do zeros of Tutte polynomials have any significance?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko: You got me there - I don't know.

Comment: Not sure why modular curves were edited out. The modular curves $X_0(n)$ have a natural plane model. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_modular_curve

Comment: And the modular curve $X_1(n)$ for $n\ge$ has an even more elementary description. Let $E_{a,b}:y^2+axy+by=x^3+bx^2$. Write down the condition for the point $P=(0,0)\in E_{a,b}$ to have exact order $n$. This gives a polynomial equation $P_n(a,b)=0$ that is an affine model for $X_1(n)$, albeit with some singular points corresponding to $(a,b)$ values at which $E_{a,b}$ is singular.

Comment: Another slightly silly example is to fix a polynomial $f(X)$ having at least two roots, and look at the sequence of curves $C_n: Y^n=f(X)$. Lang called these *superelliptic curves*. The degree and genus go to $\infty$, although the gonality never exceeds $\deg(f)$, since $(X,Y)\to Y$ is a map to $\mathbb P^1$ of degree at most $\deg(f)$. As a place they might come up, I think the $abc$ conjecture (over number fields) impiies that for all sufficiently large $n$, the set $C_n(\mathbb Q)$ contains only points with $Y\in\{0,\pm1\}$.

Comment: Even though it doesn't really answer the question because not all curves there are algebraic, and there are few families of arbitrarily high degree, I think the web site [mathcurve.com](https://mathcurve.com/courbes2d/courbes2d.shtml) (in French) deserves at least a mention here, if only because it certainly matches the *title* of the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about the affine plane curves $\Phi_n(c,t)=0$ that classify $(c,t)$ such that $t$ is a point of exact period $n$ under iteration of the quadratic map $f_c(X)=X^2+c$? These are often called *dynatomic curves* and have been much studied in recent years, especially since describing their rational points is related to the dynamnical uniform boundedness conjecture. These curves are irreducible (Bousch) and there is a nice formula for their genus (Morton) showing the genus goes to infinity. There is even some work (Poonen, Doyle, ...) showing that the gonality also grows. For the basic construction, you can see for example Sections 4.1 and 4.2 of my book *The Arithmetic of Dynamical Systems*. More generally, people study the dynatomic curves for $X^d+c$.

(I've cheated a little, one needs to include a few extra points on the curve where the point $t$ has "formal period $n$," but actual period smaller than $n$. This is Milnor's terminology.)

Comment: Thanks. This example I should have known:-)

Answer (score 3):

The caustic by n-th order reflection from the circle was advanced by [Francois Ziegler](https://mathoverflow.net/users/19276/francois-ziegler) in a comment. It is indeed known to be algebraic. As pointed out, the caustic curve of n-th order reflection from arbitrary point sources (including at infinity) was derived by Holditch "[On the nth Caustic, by Reflexion from a Circle](https://books.google.com/books?id=sp9EAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA301)", The Quarterly Journal of Pure and Applied Mathematics, vol. 2, London, 1858, pp. 301–322. This paper does include a proof that his class of curves is indeed algebraic (see p. 322 section "The Equation").

Sadly this contribution is somewhat underappreciated/overlooked leading to rediscoveries of partial results later on. For example, the case of parallel light rays (source at infinity) and the point source of the light rays on the circle for arbitrary order of reflections has been rediscovered and shown to be algebraic by Bromwich "[The Caustic, by Reflection, of a Circle](https://archive.org/details/jstor-2369905/page/n1/mode/2up)." American Journal of Mathematics, 1904, Vol 26, 33-44. Specifically pp. 43-44. As Bromwich points out these cases are equivalent to epitrochoids with given radius relations.

As a word of caution regarding the naturality of the Holditch caustic. Rays reflect at different lengths as order increases. This introduces a discrepancy in order between rays in the ray bundle. So the equality of order in Holditch's derivation is not physical if one accounts for traveling distance (say via finite traveling speed). Hence the nth order reflection curve according to Holditch has to be broken down into different order segments to achieve a physical caustic. In short, the Holditch caustics contain all the information needed to recover the physical phenomena, but there is a need for accounting for reflection order discrepancies (see Essl "[Computation of wave fronts on a disk I: numerical experiments](https://cpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/sites.uwm.edu/dist/0/236/files/2016/09/ESSL-ENTCSdarticle-21mu59l.pdf)." Electronic Notes in Theoretical Computer Science 161 (2006): 25-41.)

Given any algebraic curve as reflector, Josse and Pene ("[On the degree of caustics by reflection](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.0621.pdf)." Communications in Algebra 42.6 (2014): 2442-2475.) give the order of the caustic by reflection being an algebraic curve. This gives a different handle on the order of the algebraic curve. While the order of the Holditch caustic is directly related to the order of reflection, here it enters as the order of the reflector.

Comment: Has anyone found the genus of this caustic ? From the abstract of  your last reference I conclude that it is a rational curve for the case of circle. So it does not satisfy one of my criteria.

Comment: Ah yes, I'm sorry. Holditch already proved his caustic to be rational. This is not an example. There is another reason why I thought this might be applicable (from someone who is interested in separable PDEs). The Holditch caustic relates to separability in polar coordinates (it describes the singularities of the characteristic cone under reflection of a linear hyperbolic PDE and the separated ODE of interest being Bessel). The Lame ODE springs from separation of ellipsoidal coordinates. But this probably is way too loose an association to be of interest.

Answer (score 3):

What you call Fermat curves, are also referred to as Lamé curves, since Lamé proposed these as tools for physics, in particular crystals.  I started using them in the 1990s to describe the shapes of plants.  Recently we tested this on many botanical samples, see e.g.

- Huang, Weiwei; Li, Yueyi; Niklas, Karl J.; Gielis, Johan; Ding, Yongyan; Cao, Li; Shi, Peijian, *A Superellipse with Deformation and Its Application in Describing the Cross-Sectional Shapes of a Square Bamboo*, Symmetry **12** no. 12 (2020) 2073 https://doi.org/10.3390/sym12122073

Yours,

Johan

Answer (score 2):

I doubt this is what you seek, but the minimal polynomial for a packing of $n$
congruent disks in a square can have arbitrarily high degree:

> Szabó, Péter Gábor, Mihály Csaba Markót, and Tibor Csendes. "Global optimization in geometry—Circle packing into the square." In *Essays and Surveys in Global Optimization*, pp. 233-265. Springer, Boston, MA, 2005. [PDF download](http://www.inf.u-szeged.hu/~pszabo/Pub/45survey.pdf).

---

[image: N13]

          

<sup>The minimal polynomial for $n=13$. p.17 of Szabó et al.</sup>

---

The minimal polynomial is derived from a series of quadratic equations describing
the circle contacts.
Whether these polynomials are "naturally occurring" is a judgement call.

Comment: but where is a curve here? What I see is a polynomial in 1 variable. A curve is $F(x.y)=0$ where $F$ is a polynomial in two variables.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko: I see now that this example does not fit your criteria.